# How to calculate SVG path current degree

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to rotate object upon guideline path I created in illustrator.
I did found a way to rotate the object upon the guideline, but It's running on time and not scroll as I wish it to be.

I have this javascript code to determine the path of the object and this `animationMotion` to rotate the object automatically on time (instead of scroll).

How can I calculate the angle of the object on the path same as `animationMotion` but base it on scroll instead of time?

Some working [codepen](https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/OJywpOB) without `animationMotoion`.

```js
function positionTheElement() {
 var html = document.documentElement;
 var body = document.body;
    var scrollPercentage = (html.scrollTop + body.scrollTop - html.clientHeight) / (body.scrollHeight + 600 - html.clientHeight);
 var path = document.getElementById("tracker");
 var pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
 var pt = path.getPointAtLength(scrollPercentage * pathLen );
 var element = document.getElementById("wipe");
    element.setAttribute("transform", "translate("+ pt.x  + "," + pt.y + ")");   
};
window.addEventListener("scroll", positionTheElement);
positionTheElement();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
<g>
 <path
   id="tracker"
   d="M1343.5,32.5
           L1341,558C1339.8,583.3 1349.8,600.1 1313,611C1298,619 1247,631 1144,630C1041,629 277,630 277,630C277,630 136,625 136,658C130,687 119,719 126,747C133,775 120,1931 120,1931C120,1931 128,2029.8000000000002 208,2034.4C288,2039 1697.8,2034.4 1697.8,2034.4C1697.8,2034.4 1788,2016 1794,2124C1800,2232 1780,2700 1780,2700C1780,2700 1796.8000000000002,2794 1689.9,2793C1583,2792 938,2787 938,2787L249,2782C249,2782 151.39999999999998,2769.8 154.7,2863.9C158,2958 155,3552 155,3552C155,3552 159,3645.3999999999996 243.5,3632.7C328,3620 1484,3634 1484,3634L1491.8,3999" fill="transparent" stroke-width="0"/>
    
    
    
    
    
    <!--Wipe-->
    <g id="wipe">
        <path class="st11" d="M33.3,1c0,0-6.9-14.1-24.7-3.6S-18.5-5.8-23-0.2s-10.3-3.3-10.3-3.3s-3.4,26.2-0.5,24.8
            c0.4-0.2,0.6-0.1,0.7,0.3c1.1,2.5-2.4,16.7-2.4,16.7s-3,22.1,0.8,20.7c3.8-1.5-1.4,23.2-1.4,23.2s-7.4,23.6,5.6,2.2
            s56.9-26.1,57-15.8s1.1,20.7,3.4-11.3c0.5-6.8,6.3-46.6,0.5-31.9S31.3,4.2,33.3,1z"/>
        <line class="st12" x1="-20.3" y1="17.9" x2="-33.3" y2="21.2"/>
        <path class="st13" d="M28.1,28.2c0,0-15.7-19.9-23.1-9.8"/>
        <path class="st14" d="M26.4,67.4c0,0-0.3-3-9.8-4.2c-9.5-1.2-2.4,1.6-2.4,1.6l13,13.8c0,0-0.3-0.8-0.6-5
            C26.5,69.5,26.4,67.4,26.4,67.4L26.4,67.4"/>
        <path class="st13" d="M29.1,19l3.5,3.2c-0.7-1.5-3,5.4-4,6.6C27.6,29.9,29.1,19,29.1,19z"/>
        <path class="st15" d="M-20.3,17.9c0,0-9.6,12.3-12.7,7.4c0.1-2,0.1-4-0.2-4C-33.5,21.3-20.3,17.9-20.3,17.9z"/>
        <path class="st12" d="M-34,58.9c0,0,25.5-19.6,25.8-7.7"/>
        <path class="st15" d="M-34.2,58.8l26-7.7C-8.2,51.2-7.1,38.8-34.2,58.8z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<!-- IF you run this, the object will auto rotate but on time.
  <animateMotion 
           xlink:href="#wipe"
           dur="3s"
           begin="0s"
           fill="freeze"
            repeatCount="indefinite"
                 rotate="auto"
             >
    <mpath xlink:href="#tracker" />
  </animateMotion>
  
  -->
  </svg>
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried to add this to get the degrees, the console works but the actual rotate fails to exist.

```
var firstPoint = path.getPointAtLength(scrollPercentage * pathLen);
var secondPoint = path.getPointAtLength(scrollPercentage * (pathLen + 3));

//Get degree
var deg = Math.atan2(firstPoint.y - secondPoint.y, firstPoint.x - secondPoint.x) * (180 / Math.PI);
console.log(deg);
var element = document.getElementById("wipe");
element.setAttribute("transform", "translate("+ pt.x  + "," + pt.y + ") rotate(" + pt.deg + ")");
```

The degrees works but the transform rotation does not apply.

> Error:  attribute transform: Expected number, "…7578125)
>   rotate(undefined)".

Comment: @MaximLensky unfortunately I've tried that, that doesn't work with my javascript code.

Comment: Your "edit" calculates the angle from the origin to point pt. That's not what you're looking for is it?

Comment: @RobertLongson You are correct, I'm still working on the delta function, I'll update you if I succeed.

Comment: @RobertLongson I got this right, i can tell by the console log but the transform rotate doesn't work properly and I can't understand why..

Comment: @RobertLongson added some debugging console message

Comment: Does your debugger not reveal that pt.deg != deg

Comment: @RobertLongson maybe because the default of deg starts as 0 and changes later?

Comment: No, you have a typo. Look closer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213758/discussion-between-yotam-dahan-and-robert-longson).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already calling

```
var pt = path.getPointAtLength(scrollPercentage * pathLen );
```

If you call that function again with a small delta in either direction you'll be able to determine the direction of the path. A little trigonometry would then get the rotate you need.